# How to include helper functions in C?

Tags: c

There are 4 files:

```
helper.h //contains the signatures of functions in helper.c
helper.c //implements the signatures in helper.h
file.h //has all the includes needed to run file.h
file.c //this file includes file.h and helper.h
```

In file.c, I need to use the function that is defined in helper.c in my main function. However, file.c is saying that there is an `undefined reference to 'func_found_in_helper.c'`

Is this structure correct?

Comment: Does your `file.c` `#include "helper.h"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, provided `file.c` contains

```
#include "helper.h"
```

and when building your program you link together `helper.o` and `file.o`.

You also need to ensure you compile each of the files with `-c` so that the compiler only compiles (and not links); do the link later with all the object files.

Here's a working example (I don't actually need a `main.h` but if you have one of those, `#include` it from `main.c`):

## main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helper.h"

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  test ();
  exit (0);
}
```

## helper.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
test ()
{
  printf ("Hello world\n");
}
```

## helper.h

```
void test ();
```

## To compile

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -c -o helper.o helper.c
```

## To link

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o test main.o helper.o
```

## In a Makefile

```
test: main.o helper.o
    gcc -Wall -Werror -o test main.o helper.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -Wall -Werror -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o test
```

## To run

```
$ ./test
Hello world
```

It's a bit difficult to tell what else might be wrong without the program; my guess is you simply forgot the `-c` flag to `gcc`, or forgot to link in `helper.o`.

Comment: @User I've added an example Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

> undefined reference to 'func_found_in_helper.c'

That's a little odd, as it suggests you have tried to call the function using the '.c' extension, rather than *just* the function name.  Maybe the '.' is just a typo in the question ?

Also a linker will flag an undefined symbol, so it may also be that you have not told the linker where to find helper.o ( the helper.c file compiled to the an object file ).  The compiler will start the linker automatically.  Did you compile helper.c *first* ?